# Facebook-style conversation div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, scroll

So I'm programming a chat room. I've searched for a good answer, but I havent found one yet. 
I need the scrolling to start at the bottom, and when a new message comes in, the message (wich appears at the bottom) needs to show. But normally the message is hidden and you have to scroll down to it. I found a Jquery option that scrolls to the bottom when the content is refreshed, but it prevents you from scrolling back up.

I explained this the best I could... Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This is what I'm using:
`$("#conversation-box").animate({ scrollTop: $("#conversation-box").prop("scrollHeight") }, 500);`
But this does not allow you to scroll up since it is triggered every refresh.